# Expanding strokes leaves corners deformed in illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, corners

[image]

So here i expanded this corner which initially was round but then when i used expand or outline illustrator doesn't keep the original form. the stroke is 0.5px thick and the artboard is 52*52.

Comment: Align to pixel grid?

Comment: I don't understand ?

Comment: Do you have [Align to Pixel Grid](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/pixel-perfect.html) enabled?

Comment: No, i don't. the problem disappears with values greater than 0.3px with the round corner option

Answer (score 1):

The artboard was 52*52px , the thickness of the path was 0.5px, and the corners 0.1px, turns out at this small scale when expanding strokes, illustrator doesn't create a precise expanded shape i tried 0.3px+ and it worked well.